# How to clone multiple repositories from different project using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, git

I had an url for multiple projects inside i have multiple repos for each project
I need to clone all the repos in a directory and find git branches.

i tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
project=(aa bb cc)
aa=(a b c)
bb=("d" "e")
cc=("g")
for i in "${project[@]}"
do
    echo "${!i}"
    for j in  @{$i}
    do
        echo $j
    done
done
```

But not getting the output .

Comment: Hello and welcome to U&L SE. As it stands your question is not very clear. Please edit it to include what output you actually expect.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you want to iterate through arrays using dynamic arrays name.
You can do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
project=(aa bb cc)
aa=(a b c)
bb=("d" "e")
cc=("g")
for i in "${project[@]}"
do
    var="$i[@]"
    for j in  ${!var}
    do
        echo j=$j
    done
done
```

Comment: but here i need to print all the values in project lists

Comment: this is exactly what you'll get